# Safety vs speed of multithreading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have an array that I want to be updated by multiple threads simultaneously, what's the best/fastest way to go about doing that? For example, say I have the following code:

```
std::vector<float> vec;
vec.push_back(0.f);
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    std::thread([&]{ 
        // SAFETY CONSTRUCTS GO HERE
        vec[0] += 1; // OR MAYBE HERE
        // AND HERE? 
    });
}
// wait a little while, i.e. I was too lazy to write out joins
std::cout << vec[0];
```

If I want this to be safe and finally print the value 10000, what would be the best/fastest way to do this?

Comment: In your example only one thread can work on the single vector element at any given time. Therefore it cannot be faster than on a single thread (it will be much slower with necessary barriers). Also because all 10000 of them are potentially  launched before any of them exit, they will all block each others cpu resources. At least if compiled for a single thread the loop would also likely be optimized to a constant by the compiler.

Comment: It is really hard to generalize how to optimize threading with such a basic example. Most problems do not involve just a single variable. Also how is that variable going to be used? Are some threads only reading the variable while others write to it? If so what is the ratio of readers to writers. etc... etc...

Comment: Couldn't you use `std::atomic` in this case? I removed my answer because I don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: This question isn't about **safety**, it's about **correctness**. There are all kinds of things this code could do to have **well-defined** results; only some of them actually produce **correct** results.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you've given, the best/safest way would be to not launch threads, and simply update `v[0]` in the loop.   The overhead of launching and synchronising threads will probably exceed any benefit you get by doing some operations in parallel.

`v` is a non-atomic object (`std::vector<float>`) and `v[0]` is actually a function call.   Such objects, and their non-static member functions, cannot protect themselves from concurrent access by multiple threads.   To use them from multiple threads, every direct usage of `v` (and `v[0]`) must be synchronised.

Generally, safety involving concurrently executing threads is achieved by synchronising access to any variables (or, more generally, memory) that are updated and accessed by multiple threads.

If using a mutex, that normally means all threads which access shared data must first grab the mutex, do the operation on shared variables (e.g. update `v[0]`), and then release the mutex.    If a thread has not grabbed (or has grabbed and then released) the mutex, then all operations it does must NOT touch the shared variables.

If you want performance through threading, you will need to have a significant amount of the work done in each thread without ANY access to shared variables.    That work, since parts can be executed concurrently, can potentially be executed in less total elapsed time.   For that to represent a performance benefit, the gains (e.g. by doing a lot of operations concurrently) need to exceed the costs (of launching threads, of synchronising access to any data that is accessed by multiple threads).

Which is highly unlikely in anything similar to the code you have shown.

The point is that there is always a trade-off between speed and safety, when threads share any data.    Safety requires updating of shared variables to be synchronised - without exception.    A performance gain is generally derived from the things that do not need to be synchronised (i.e. that don't access variables shared between threads) and can be executed in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

There's no single magic technique to have highly performant parallel access to shared data, but there are a few general techniques you'll see fairly often.

I'll use the example of summing an array in parallel for my answer, but these techniques apply pretty generally to many parallel algorithms.

## 1) Avoid sharing data in the first place

This is likely to be the safest and fastest method.  Instead of having your worker threads directly update the shared state, have each of them work with their own local state, and then have your main thread combine the results.  For the array sum example, this could look something like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> toSum = getSomeVector();
    std::vector<int> sums(NUM_THREADS);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    int chunkSize = std::ceil(toSum.size() / (float)NUM_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        auto chunkBegin = toSum.begin() + (i * chunkSize);
        auto chunkEnd = chunkBegin + chunkSize;

        threads.emplace_back([chunkBegin, chunkEnd](int& result) mutable {
            for (; chunkBegin != chunkEnd; ++chunkBegin) {
                result += *chunkBegin;
            }
        }, std::ref(sums[i]));
    }

    for (std::thread& thd : threads) {
        thd.join();
    }

    int finalSum = 0;
    for (int partialSum : sums) {
        finalSum += partialSum;
    }

    std::cout << finalSum << '\n';
}
```

Since each thread only ever operates on its own partial sum, they cannot interfere with each other, and no extra synchronization is needed.  You have to to a little bit of extra work at the end to add all the partial sums up, but the number of partial results is small, so this overhead should be pretty minimal.

## 2) Mutual exclusion

Instead of having each thread operate on its own state, you can protect shared state with a locking mechanism.  Fairly often, this is a mutex, but there are lots of different locking primitives that have slightly different roles.  The point here is to make sure only one thread is ever working with the shared state at a time.  Be very careful when using this technique to avoid accessing the shared state within a tight loop.  Since only one thread can hold the lock at a time, it's very easy to accidentally transform you fancy parallel code back into single-threaded code by making it so that only one thread can ever be working at a time.

For example, consider the following:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> toSum = getSomeVector();
    int sum = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    int chunkSize = std::ceil(toSum.size() / (float)NUM_THREADS);
    std::mutex mtx;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        auto chunkBegin = toSum.begin() + (i * chunkSize);
        auto chunkEnd = chunkBegin + chunkSize;

        threads.emplace_back([chunkBegin, chunkEnd, &mtx, &sum]() mutable {
            for (; chunkBegin != chunkEnd; ++chunkBegin) {
                std::lock_guard guard(mtx);
                sum += *chunkBegin;
            }
        });
    }

    for (std::thread& thd : threads) {
        thd.join();
    }

    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Since each thread locks `mtx` within its loop, only one thread can ever be doing any work at a time.  There is no parallelization here, and this code is likely to be *slower* than the equivalent single-threaded code due to the extra overhead of allocating threads and locking and unlocking the mutex.

Instead try to do as much as possible independantly, and access your shared state as infrequently as possible.  For this example, you can do something similar to the example in (1) and build up partial sums within each thread, only adding them to the shared sum once at the end:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> toSum = getSomeVector();
    int sum = 0;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    int chunkSize = std::ceil(toSum.size() / (float)NUM_THREADS);
    std::mutex mtx;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        auto chunkBegin = toSum.begin() + (i * chunkSize);
        auto chunkEnd = chunkBegin + chunkSize;

        threads.emplace_back([chunkBegin, chunkEnd, &mtx, &sum]() mutable {
            int partialSum = 0;
            for (; chunkBegin != chunkEnd; ++chunkBegin) {
                partialSum += *chunkBegin;
            }
            {
                std::lock_guard guard(mtx);
                sum += partialSum;
            }
        });
    }

    for (std::thread& thd : threads) {
        thd.join();
    }

    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

## 3) Atomic variables

Atomic variables are variables that can be "safely" shared between threads.  They are very powerful, but also very easy to get wrong.  You have to worry about things like memory-ordering constraints, and when you get them wrong it can be very difficult to debug and figure out what you did wrong.

At their core, atomic variables could be implemented as a simple variable whose operations are guarded by a mutex or similar.  The magic all lies in the implementation, which often uses special CPU instructions to coordinate access to the variables at the CPU level to avoid a lot of the overhead of locking and unlocking.

Atomics aren't a magic bullet though.  There is still overhead involved, and you can still shoot yourself in the foot by accessing your atomics too frequently.  Your CPU does a lot of caching, and having multiple threads writing to an atomic variable likely means spilling the contents back out to memory, or at least to a higher level of cache.  Once again, if you can avoid accessing your shared state withing tight loops in your thread, you should do so:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> toSum = getSomeVector();
    std::atomic<int> sum(0);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    int chunkSize = std::ceil(toSum.size() / (float)NUM_THREADS);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        auto chunkBegin = toSum.begin() + (i * chunkSize);
        auto chunkEnd = chunkBegin + chunkSize;


        threads.emplace_back([chunkBegin, chunkEnd, &sum]() mutable {
            int partialSum = 0;
            for (; chunkBegin != chunkEnd; ++chunkBegin) {
                partialSum += *chunkBegin;
            }
            // Since we don't care about the order that the threads update the sum,
            // we can use memory_order_relaxed.  This is a rabbit-hole I won't get
            // too deep into here though.
            sum.fetch_add(partialSum, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        });
    }

    for (std::thread& thd : threads) {
        thd.join();
    }

    std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```